# Adding runat=Server removes style from select control

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use [this control](http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/) and be able to access it from the code backend (cs file). I started with the code below which works:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#foundImages").imagepicker({
           hide_select: true,
           show_label: true
       });
   });
```

```
<select id="foundImages" class="image-picker show-labels show-html">
    <option data-img-label="Awww" data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/220/200" value="1">Cute Kitten 1</option>
    <option data-img-label="Yeah" data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/180/200" value="2">Cute Kitten 2</option>
    <option data-img-label="Ohai" data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/130/200" value="3">Cute Kitten 3</option>
    <option data-img-label="Plop" data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/270/200" value="4">Cute Kitten 4</option>
</select>
```

But when I add `runat="server"` to it, so I can access it from the .cs file, the drop control just looks like a standard combobox. Any idea why the style is removed when I add `runat="server"` - or is there another way to access the `<select>` control from my cs file?

Thank you!

Comment: runat server component are pre-rendered in the server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `runat="server"` to the select you turn it into a server side control. And in this case, the ID of the generated HTML select would be `foundImages.ClientID` (you can check this using View Source). This means you have to change this line:

```
$("#foundImages").imagepicker({
```

With this line:

```
$("#<%=foundImages.ClientID%>").imagepicker({
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `'runat="server"'`, try adding `'clientidmode="Static"'`.

Sometimes, `ASP.NET` will change the `ID` on you, and so your `CSS` and `JavaScript` may appear to be broken. However, by setting the Client ID Mode to `'Static'`, you are forcing `ASP.NET` to leave your ID alone.

Comment: Note that if you have the same ID on a control in your master page(s) and in your aspx page, your page will break when ClientIdMode is set to Static

Answer (score 1):

Following on from other answers, that correctly state that the ID may change (unless `ClientIDMode` is set), the simplest way around the issue you're seeing is to use your element's CSS classes instead.

You've already assigned the class `image-picker` to your dropdown, so there's no reason not to do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".image-picker").imagepicker({
       hide_select: true,
       show_label: true
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First Use this for control

```
'clientidmode="Static"'
```

then 
get control from script like this

```
$("#<%=img.ClientID%>").imagepicker({...});
```